# Retrieve data of custom VSTO addin

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, add-in

I'm playing with VSTO Add-in to add a feature that may be useful for me.
So what I've done so far is declaring my ribbon.xml as below:

```
<tabs>
  <tab idMso="TabAppointment" insertAfterMso="TabAddIns">
    <group id="TripGroup" label="Add Trip">
      <dropDown id="TripBooking_Tab_AddMeetingBefore"
                getLabel="GetLabel"
                getSelectedItemIndex="TripBooking_Tab_AddMeeting_GetSelectedItemIndex"
                getItemCount="TripBooking_Tab_AddMeeting_GetItemCount"
                getItemID="TripBooking_Tab_AddMeeting_GetItemID"
                getItemLabel="TripBooking_Tab_AddMeeting_GetItemLabel"
                onAction="TripBooking_Tab_AddMeetingBefore_OnAction"/>
      <separator/>
      <dropDown id="TripBooking_Tab_AddMeetingAfter"
                getLabel="GetLabel"
                getSelectedItemIndex="TripBooking_Tab_AddMeeting_GetSelectedItemIndex"
                getItemCount="TripBooking_Tab_AddMeeting_GetItemCount"
                getItemID="TripBooking_Tab_AddMeeting_GetItemID"
                getItemLabel="TripBooking_Tab_AddMeeting_GetItemLabel"
                onAction="TripBooking_Tab_AddMeetingAfter_OnAction"/>
    </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
```

All works like a charm and I get my 2 `dropdown` in the UI.
Now question is : How do I retrieve the value of the `dropdown` for each new appointment I do?

Comment: If you post the procedures for `getSelectedItemIndex`, `getItemCount`, `getItemID` and `getItemLabel` I can give a more detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

I would set variables on the `OnAction` event of the `dropDown` and when loading the default values.

```
public void OnAction_Dropdown(Office.IRibbonControl control, string itemId, int index)
{
    try
    {
        switch (control.Id) //do a lookup of the value from your list based on the index
        {
            case "TripBooking_Tab_AddMeetingBefore":
                // set a variable here
                break;
            case "TripBooking_Tab_AddMeetingAfter":
                // set a variable here
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // format message
        var userMessage = new StringBuilder()
            .AppendLine("Contact your system administrator.")
            .AppendLine("Procedure: " + caller.Name.Trim())
            .AppendLine("Description: " + ex.ToString())
            .ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(userMessage, "Unexpected Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried that, but how do I retrieve these values in the appointment instance (Outlook.Appointment) user is currently creating ?

Comment: I think this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-outlook-item?view=vs-2017) may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve current value. Instead, you need to have it in  your addin (as a variable/field) and make the control render it, react on control events and update your value accordingly.

When you need the value, you just use your internal variable.

This approach of not allowing user to access or manipulate ribbon controls directly at runtime is a good thing, and prevents add-ins from breaking each other, or the built-in UI, like it used to be in the pre-ribbon (command bars) time. Microsoft switched to this approach when they first introduced the ribbon in 2007.

Somewhat related: 
[How to set default value in dropdown control for Excel custom ribbon control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906620/how-to-set-default-value-in-dropdown-control-for-excel-custom-ribbon-control)